# Wrote Binary Search algorithms for Python, both a recursive and iterative version. How would you judge their efficiency?

Tags: python, performance, recursion, iteration, binary-search

First things first, let me tell you how I am actually using the algorithms, lest any confusion arises, since this is NOT the typical use of a Binary Search algorithm.

I needed the functions for purely academic / testing purposes to compare speeds against other functions I've tested, including Python's in-built *isinstance()* and *in* methods / operands.

I'm going through a string that contains digits and letters and testing whether a character from it is an integer.

Thus, the application of the following algorithms upon each iteration (i.e. character) of the loop upon the string is thus:

`binSearch("0123456789", "4", 0, 10)`

The "4" is just as an example as you can tell.

`binSearch2("0123456789", "w")`

The "w" is just as an example as you can tell.

**NOTE:** I am aware of the existence of the `bisect` module. That's not the point and object of my experiment and exercise, though.

---

#RECURSIVE VERSION BELOW

```
def binSearch(list, digit, low, up):

mid = (low + up) // 2
midd = list[mid]

if digit == midd:
    return True
elif digit > midd:
    if mid == 9: return False
    return True and binSearch(list, digit, mid, up)
elif digit < midd:
    return True and binSearch(list, digit, low, mid)
```

#ITERATIVE VERSION BELOW

```
def binSearch2(list, digit):

low = 0
up = len(list)
mid = (low + up) // 2

while mid > 0:

    if digit == list[mid]: 
        return True

    elif digit > list[mid]:
        low = mid
        if low == 9: break

    else:
        up = mid

    mid = (low + up) // 2
    #print(low, mid, up)

if digit == list[mid]: return True

return False
```

Comments welcome !

Comment: Run them, and profile them to measure the metric you are using to gauge efficiency.

Comment: What is the point of `True and binSearch(list, digit, mid, up)`?

Comment: You can measure the time of execution of each function for similar inputs and compare averages. But that would be machine dependent (if it doesn't cause any problem to your experiment)

Comment: You can judge the efficiency without running the code. The iterative version uses less memory and doesn't have the overhead of repeated recursive function calls.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I don't think you're quite getting my question. I'm asking whether the code I've written is the *most efficient version* of the Binary Search algorithm possible, **NOT** how fast they run!!!

Comment: Efficient in terms of what? Use of characters?

Comment: @Alexander If you do not define how you measure efficiency it is impossible to make a suggestion. You do not seem to be interested in execution speed. So, what is efficient for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your functions can be improved by making sure that `mid` is excluded from the range of indexes that you consider on the next pass (either a recursive call, or a subsequent loop). Since you just checked if the `mid` index has the value you want (and it didn't), you can exclude `mid` from the upper interval, by setting `low` to `mid+1` on the next pass. It's already being excluded from the lower intervals, since the `up` index is beyond the end of the interval (it's half-open).

You've also hard-coded a strange base failure case into the function, where you check for `mid==9`. That won't work properly for a whole lot of inputs (such as shorter strings), and may cause your code to run forever, or raise exceptions depending on where the needle character is relative to the characters in the haystack string (try searching for `' '` with your current code). The proper base case test is `low >= up`, which indicates that your search interval is empty. For the iterative code, you'd keep looping as long as `low < up`.

Here's how I'd update your functions:

```
def binSearch(list, digit, low, up):
    if low >= up:        # base case moved here, tested properly
        return False
    mid = (low + up) // 2
    midd = list[mid]
    if digit == midd:
        return True
    elif digit > midd:   # no more base case code in this block
        return binSearch(list, digit, mid+1, up)   # exclude mid from the next interval
    elif digit < midd:
        return binSearch(list, digit, low, mid)


def binSearch2(list, digit):
    low = 0
    up = len(list)
    while low < up:  # base case test is here now
        mid = (low + up) // 2  # move this here, so we don't need to repeat it
        if digit == list[mid]: 
            return True
        elif digit > list[mid]:
            low = mid + 1      # skip mid when moving up, no longer test base case here
        else:
            up = mid
    return False
```

Comment: @Blcknght thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! You're the only one who seems to have understood my question correctly and provided the answer I need !!!

For reference, here's what I tested and discovered:
A text file of approximate ~2 GB size with ~62 MILLION lines of text in it, here's how the four functions (2 my own, 2 *YOURS*) perform, in seconds:

```151.44810819625854 my recursive```

```138.65630173683167 my iterative```

```144.89938354492188 YOUR recursive```

```128.67388534545898 YOUR iterative```

THANK YOU !!!